# Dynamically modify itemid based on current menu

Tags: joomla, url-rewriting

I have a site where a series of articles need to show up under two different menus. Depending on the active menu, different modules are displayed. The problem is that the internal links in the articles have an itemid in them which ties them to only one menu.

The solution I have in mind is to modify index.php for the template I use for those menus, and do a search and replace for all internal links - setting the itemid based on the current id. Keeping in mind that mod_rewrite won't work in this situation, is there a graceful way to do this in Joomla?

I suspect that I'd need to take
`<jdoc:include type="component" />`
and, instead of just including the component, read the content into a variable, do the search and replace and spit it back out. How might I go about doing this?

Are there simpler approaches to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the item id from the internal links. By default, the item id should be inherited from the current item.

Comment: Thanks Brent. Pretty new to Joomla as was made obvious by my question :).

Comment: No problem, Joomla is a pretty sophisticated piece of software. It takes some time to learn all the details.